# Java State Exception: get field slot from row col-1 failed

Tags: android, sql, eclipse, exception, row

I have an SQL database as follows:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;

public class sqlDatabase {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_PURCHASEREFUND = "_purchaserefund";  
public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "_location";
public static final String KEY_SHOPTYPE = "_shoptype";
public static final String KEY_PRICE = "_price";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "_datevalue";
public static final String KEY_CARDUSED = "_cardused";
public static final String KEY_DATEVALUE = "_carddate";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "receiptdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "receipttable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  

private receiptDBhelper receiptHelper;
private final Context receiptContext;
private SQLiteDatabase receiptDatabase;


private static class receiptDBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public receiptDBhelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }       

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase rdb) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        rdb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_PURCHASEREFUND + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_DATEVALUE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_CARDUSED + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_LOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SHOPTYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_PRICE + " TEXT NOT NULL);"          
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase rdb, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        rdb.execSQL("DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(rdb);
    }

}

public sqlDatabase(Context c){
    receiptContext = c;
}

public sqlDatabase open() throws SQLException {
    receiptHelper = new receiptDBhelper(receiptContext);
    receiptDatabase = receiptHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;        
}

public void close(){
    receiptHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String purchaserefund, String shoptype,
        String location, String price, String cardused) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ContentValues dbcv = new ContentValues();

    long saveddatevalue = new Date().getTime();

    SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date = new Date();


    dbcv.put(KEY_PURCHASEREFUND, purchaserefund);
    dbcv.put(KEY_SHOPTYPE, shoptype);
    dbcv.put(KEY_LOCATION, location);
    dbcv.put(KEY_PRICE, price);
    dbcv.put(KEY_CARDUSED, cardused);
    dbcv.put(KEY_DATE, dateformat.format(date));
    dbcv.put(KEY_DATEVALUE, saveddatevalue);

    return receiptDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, dbcv);
}

public String getDate(String cardused) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] receiptDBcolumns = { KEY_DATE, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_SHOPTYPE, KEY_PRICE, KEY_DATEVALUE, KEY_CARDUSED };
    Cursor receiptcursor = receiptDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, receiptDBcolumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String receiptdate = "";

    String outputcardcheck = cardused;

    long datevalue = new Date().getTime();

    long millisIn32Days = 32 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 

    long daysBeforeLong = (datevalue - millisIn32Days);     

    int iDate = receiptcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE);
    int iDateValue = receiptcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATEVALUE);
    int iCardUsed = receiptcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CARDUSED);

    for (receiptcursor.moveToFirst(); !receiptcursor.isAfterLast(); receiptcursor.moveToNext()) {

        long inputDateValue = receiptcursor.getLong(iDateValue);

        String outputCardUsed = receiptcursor.getString(iCardUsed);

        if (outputCardUsed == outputcardcheck) { 
            if (inputDateValue < daysBeforeLong) {
                receiptdate = receiptdate + receiptcursor.getString(iDate) + "\n";
            }       
        }
    }

    return receiptdate;
}

public String getLocation(String cardused) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] receiptDBcolumns = { KEY_DATE, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_SHOPTYPE, KEY_PRICE, KEY_DATEVALUE };
    Cursor receiptcursor = receiptDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, receiptDBcolumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String receiptlocation = "";

    String outputcardcheck = cardused;

    long datevalue = new Date().getTime();

    long millisIn32Days = 32 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 

    long daysBeforeLong = (datevalue - millisIn32Days); 

    int iLocation = receiptcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATION);
    int iDateValue = receiptcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATEVALUE);
    int iCardUsed = receiptcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CARDUSED);

    for (receiptcursor.moveToFirst(); !receiptcursor.isAfterLast(); receiptcursor.moveToNext()) {

        long inputDateValue = receiptcursor.getLong(iDateValue);

        String outputCardUsed = receiptcursor.getString(iCardUsed);

        if (outputCardUsed == outputcardcheck) {
            if (inputDateValue < daysBeforeLong) {
                receiptlocation = receiptlocation + receiptcursor.getString(iLocation) + "\n";
            }       
        }
    }

    return receiptlocation;
}

public String getShopType(String cardused) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] receiptDBcolumns = { KEY_DATE, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_SHOPTYPE, KEY_PRICE, KEY_DATEVALUE };
    Cursor receiptcursor = receiptDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, receiptDBcolumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String receiptshoptype = "";

    String outputcardcheck = cardused;

    long datevalue = new Date().getTime();

    long millisIn32Days = 32 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 

    long daysBeforeLong = (datevalue - millisIn32Days);     

    int iShopType = receiptcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_SHOPTYPE);
    int iDateValue = receiptcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATEVALUE);
    int iCardUsed = receiptcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CARDUSED);

    for (receiptcursor.moveToFirst(); !receiptcursor.isAfterLast(); receiptcursor.moveToNext()) {

        long inputDateValue = receiptcursor.getLong(iDateValue);

        String outputCardUsed = receiptcursor.getString(iCardUsed);

        if (outputCardUsed == outputcardcheck) {
            if (inputDateValue < daysBeforeLong) {
                receiptshoptype = receiptshoptype + receiptcursor.getString(iShopType) + "\n";
            }       
        }
    }

    return receiptshoptype;
}

public String getPrice(String cardused) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] receiptDBcolumns = { KEY_DATE, KEY_LOCATION, KEY_SHOPTYPE, KEY_PRICE, KEY_DATEVALUE };
    Cursor receiptcursor = receiptDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, receiptDBcolumns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String receiptprice = "";

    String outputcardcheck = cardused;

    long datevalue = new Date().getTime();

    long millisIn32Days = 32 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 

    long daysBeforeLong = (datevalue - millisIn32Days);     

    int iPrice = receiptcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE);
    int iDateValue = receiptcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATEVALUE);
    int iCardUsed = receiptcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CARDUSED);

    for (receiptcursor.moveToFirst(); !receiptcursor.isAfterLast(); receiptcursor.moveToNext()) {

        long inputDateValue = receiptcursor.getLong(iDateValue);

        String outputCardUsed = receiptcursor.getString(iCardUsed);

            if (outputCardUsed == outputcardcheck) {
                if (inputDateValue < daysBeforeLong) {
                    receiptprice = receiptprice + receiptcursor.getString(iPrice) + "\n";
                }       
            }
    }

    return receiptprice;
}
```

}

Where the (String cardused) statement is a string called from the class where I wish to call the database values to (relevant code as follows):
    sqlDatabase receiptdb = new sqlDatabase(statement.this);

```
    receiptdb.open();

    String receiptdate = receiptdb.getDate(cardused);
    String receiptlocation = receiptdb.getLocation(cardused);
    String receiptshoptype = receiptdb.getShopType(cardused);
    String receiptprice = receiptdb.getPrice(cardused);

    receiptdb.close();
```

I've just added in the (String cardused) parameters to the "get" methods, the entire database was working perfectly before but now it's coming up with this error!

Is there any other way to pass the value of a string into the SQL database for comparison when outputting results, or has something gone wrong in my code here?

Thanks!